# How to update to Cordova WebView to its latest version (version 4.1.1 or to its higher) .?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to update to cordova webview to its latest version in my android project .  The current version of cordova webview in my project is - org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView (4.0.0) , i need to update it to the latest. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can update Cordova by running this in the terminal

`npm update -g cordova ionic`

[this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-update-cordova-and-ionic/3736) post goes into more detail if you run into more issues, for example, you may need to update each platform you currently have, so if you have ios and android you would want to use this after running the npm command:

```
$ cordova platform update android

$ cordova platform update ios
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to update cordova to latest version

npm update -g cordova

Use this syntax to install a specific version

npm install -g cordova@3.0.0

Note : 3.0.0 can be replaced by desired version.

Comment: thanks for your answers.. i hav already done this and my cordova version is 6.0.0 . But recently i got a message from google playstore that i need to update CordovaWebView to its higher version (" latest version of Apache Cordova WebView  version 4.1.1 and higher ") .